# onClick ListView Help

Tags: android, listview, onclick

Ok, I'm very new to Android and Programming in general. I followed the tutorial on the android developers page for creating a list view. Now I actually want to do something with it. I have it working for going to one view, but I want two items in the list each going to a  different Activity. Here's the code I have already.

```
package com.pais.convert;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class list extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_chooser);
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, choose));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, tempConvert.class);
        intent.putExtra("KEY_SELECTED_INDEX", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    }
```

I have it going to one different activity but how can I have two separate items in the listView each going to different activities. But still launching from the same list?

Thanks For All The Help.

Answer (score 1):

For a ListActivity, the easiest thing to do is to override `onListItemClick` in the activity itself.

EDIT:

Here's what I mean:

```
public class test extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      String[] choose = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.list_chooser);
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, choose));

      ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Start another activity to do something with the selected item.
        // I'll assume the other activity is defined in the class
        // AnotherActivity:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
        // now you can add additional information to the intent for the
        // other activity to use. For instance, to pass just the index of the
        // selected item, you could code:
        intent.putExtra("KEY_SELECTED_INDEX", position);
        // (The string "KEY_SELECTED_INDEX" is an arbitrary string you choose
        // to name this piece of data. AnotherActivity will use the same name
        // to retrieve it. Other extras would be added under different names.)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then you would have to define a separate activity to display the second view:

```
public class AnotherActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int position = intent.getIntExtra("KEY_SELECTED_INDEX", -1);
        if (position == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No selection to show!", Toast.DURATION_LONG)
                 .show();
        }

        // continue with setting up the activity
    }
}
```

You also would need to add this second activity to your app's manifest file.

Comment: So I added        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
          int position, long id) { to the code but how do i get this to point to the activity "view" I want to get it to, and open it.

Comment: First, you don't need to call `setOnItemClickListener`. Just override `onListItemClick`. To open another view, you typically start a new activity (as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#ActivatingComponents)): you create a `new Intent(this, NewViewActivity.class);` and use it to call `startActivity`. When the user presses the back button from that activity, the app will return to your list activity. (If you don't want that, call `finish` after calling `startActivity`).

Comment: I did something like this. `@Override OnItemClickListener` the first line. Below it `new Intent(this, view.class);` and 'startActivity(view.class);` below that I inserted a Auto-Generated method stub. The @Override and OnItemClickListener are giving me an error. I have a feeling that I still have done something majorly wrong... As you can tell I am very new to Programming.

Comment: The method you need to override is named `onListItemClick`, not `OnItemClickListener`. Use Eclipse to help: move the cursor to a line between methods, type ctrl-space, and then type the first few letters of the method name. When you see the method you want to override, select it and press enter. Then fill in the body.

Comment: Ok so now i have `@Override onListItemCLick(l, v, position, id):` The @Override is still giving me an error about not having an enum body and eclipse has no solution for it... I dont really know much about emums or how to implement. For the body of the OnListItemCLick. Im guessing the l is the listview, the v for identifying the view clicked. I dont really understand position or id. What should the body have for what I want to do.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the code you have now? There shouldn't be anything about enums in this.

Comment: Ok I edited it. Would I still need `ListView lv = getListView();
      lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`. Thanks again for your time

Comment: @Ted Hopp this solved my problem but what if I want to have 2 or more things in the list but each go to different activities. Would I just add new intents like intent1?

Comment: Well, you can't run two activities at once. You can pass the array of selected items to an activity, which could arrange to present them in sequence, if that makes sense for your application.

Comment: I dont want to run 2 activities at once I want one to go to one, and the other go to the other, completely independent of each other. So if the user went back it would have the list again. So if it was a converter and they choose what they want "Temperature" and it goes to the temperature converter activity. If they want to go back and do a different kind of conversion like pressure they click on "Pressure" in the list and it goes to an activity that converts pressure.

Comment: Ah. You would then work out in your `onListItemClick` method which activity to start and create the appropriate intent. Or, depending on how different the UI portion would be for temperature and pressure, you could use the same activity class for both and initialize the activity differently based on what was passed in the intent.

Comment: So how would I work in the onListItemClick to choose the right activity to start and create the appropriate intent as you said? So if I have one activity called tempConvert and another called presConvert how would I tell it to go to the right one based on where the user clicked?